# How to get the current cache/document (Sales Order/Shipment) outside the context of a graph

Tags: acumatica

I'm currently implementing a new carrier method and would like to access additional information on the Shipment/Sales Order object which is not passed through in the `GetRateQuote` & `Ship` functions of the implemented ICarrierService class.

The carrier method implements the `ICarrierService` interface and subsequently does not have access to a Graph where one would typically be able to access the current (cached?) document, etc.

How could I, for example, access the shipment number for which the `Ship` function is called?

My ultimate goal is to be able to generate a label for the shipment package, and in order to do so, I need to obtain the Shipment Number.

```
using PX.Api;
using PX.CarrierService;
using PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.Reports;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Reports;
using PX.Reports.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyCarriers.CollectCarrier
{
    public class CollectCarrier : ICarrierService
    {
        private List<CarrierMethod> methods;
        private List<string> attributes;

        public IList<string> Attributes => (IList<string>)this.attributes;
        public string CarrierID { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public ReadOnlyCollection<CarrierMethod> AvailableMethods => this.methods.AsReadOnly();

        public CollectCarrier()
        {
            this.methods = new List<CarrierMethod>(1);
            this.methods.Add(new CarrierMethod("CLT", "Collect"));
            this.attributes = new List<string>(1);
        }

        [...]

        public CarrierResult<ShipResult> Ship(CarrierRequest cr)
        {
            if (cr.Packages == null || cr.Packages.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("CarrierRequest.Packages must be contain atleast one Package");
            }

            CarrierResult<ShipResult> carrierResult;

            try
            {
                CarrierResult<RateQuote> rateQuote = this.GetRateQuote(cr, true);
                ShipResult result = new ShipResult(rateQuote.Result);

                //Report Parameters
                Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();

                // ************************************************************************************
                // At this point, I would like to be able to retrieve the current SOShipment's Shipment Number
                // ************************************************************************************
                parameters["shipmentNbr"] = "000009"; // Hard-coded this value to get the PDF generated.

                //Report Processing
                PX.Reports.Controls.Report _report = PXReportTools.LoadReport("SO645000", null);
                PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(_report, parameters, SettingsProvider.Instance.Default);
                ReportNode reportNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(_report);

                //Generation PDF
                result.Image = PX.Reports.Mail.Message.GenerateReport(reportNode, ReportProcessor.FilterPdf).First();
                result.Format = "pdf";

                result.Data.Add(new PackageData(
                    cr.Packages.FirstOrDefault().RefNbr,
                    this.RandomString(6),
                    result.Image,
                    "pdf"
                )
                {
                    TrackingData = this.RandomString(6)
                });

                carrierResult = new CarrierResult<ShipResult>(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (this.LogTrace)
                {
                    this.WriteToLog(ex, this.GetType().Name + ".Ship().Exception");
                }
                List<Message> messageList = this.HandleException(ex);
                messageList?.Insert(0, new Message("", "Failed to generate the collection label: "));
                carrierResult = new CarrierResult<ShipResult>(false, null, (IList<Message>)messageList);
            }
            return carrierResult;
        }

        [...]
    }
}
```

For reference, the CarrierRequest object that is passed to the functions contain the following information:

```
public class CarrierRequest
    {
        public string ThirdPartyAccountID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ThirdPartyPostalCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ThirdPartyCountryCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IAddressBase Shipper
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IContactBase ShipperContact
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IAddressBase Origin
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IContactBase OriginContact
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IAddressBase Destination
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IContactBase DestinationContact
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IList<CarrierBox> Packages
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IList<CarrierBoxEx> PackagesEx
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IList<string> Methods
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DateTime ShipDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public UnitsType Units
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public bool SaturdayDelivery
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool Resedential
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool Insurance
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CuryID
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IList<string> Attributes
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public decimal InvoiceLineTotal
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string FreightClass
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool SkipAddressVerification
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IList<ISETerritoriesMappingBase> TerritoriesMapping
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public CarrierRequest(UnitsType units, string curyID)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(curyID))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("curyID");
            }

            Units = units;
            CuryID = curyID;
        }
    }
```

I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616506/get-current-cache-outside-of-graph) here on SO, but I'm not entirely sure that is applicable to my specific request?

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See below as an option to loop through your currents and search for the specific current object:

```
SOShipment ship = null;

for (int i = 0; i < Caches.Currents.Length; i++)
{
   if (Caches.Currents[i].GetType() == typeof(SOShipment))
   {
      ship = (SOShipment)Caches.Currents[i];
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gerhard, Thank you soo much for the response. I tested the caches.currents method and it appears that the Currents field is empty.